# Divergence of the sum of the divergent integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, divergent-series

I want to prove the divergence of: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx=\int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx +\int_{2}^{4} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx+\int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$$

- $\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$ diverges to $+\infty$
- $\int_{2}^{4} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$ diverges to $-\infty$
- $\int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$ diverges to $+\infty$

How can I prove that the sum of theese three integrals also diverges?

Comment: "the sum of these three integrals also diverges" Please explain precisely what you mean by that.

Comment: The integrand functions has two simple poles in $x=2$ and $x=4$, so it is not Riemann (nor Lebesgue) integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$. This is different from saying that the integral is divergent: the integral does not even exist.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: But isn't it correct to say that the *improper* integral is divergent?

Comment: I think it is a matter of definitions, but usually I say that an improper integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is divergent when $\lim_{a\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx = \pm\infty$. In this case the integral over $[0,4]$ is not even defined.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's strange, the command in my math book tells me to check the convergence of this integral. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Its principal value is $-\dfrac{\ln2}2$.

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik: About convergence, because $\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx$ does not exist, $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can first write

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx +\int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx+\int_{3}^{4} \frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx+\int_{4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\mathrm dx$.

Then you can show that any one of the first 3 integrals diverges, using that $\int\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\;dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert\frac{x-4}{x-2}\rvert+C$,
to conclude that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\;dx$ diverges.

For example, $\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\;dx=\lim_{t\to2^{-}}\int_0^{t}\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\;dx=\lim_{t\to2^{-}}\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln\lvert\frac{t-4}{t-2}\rvert-\ln2\right]=\infty$,

so $\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^2-6x+8}\;dx$ diverges.